# redux-react-route v4/v5 push() is not working inside thunk action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

In `index.js` push directly or throw dispatch works well:

```js
...
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, routerMiddleware(browserHistory))
)
// in v5 this line is deprecated
export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

history.push('/any') // works well
store.dispatch(push('/any')) // works well

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

`App.js`

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="/any" component={Any} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(/*...*/)(App))
```

but in `redux-thunk` action all attempts ends by rewriting url, but **without re-rendering**

```js
...
export function myAction(){
  return (dispatch) => {
    // fetch something and then I want to redirect...
    history.push('/any') // change url but not re-render
    dispatch(push('/any')) // change url but not re-render
    store.dispatch(push('/any')) // change url but not re-render
  }
}
```

This `myAction` is calling fetch() inside and should redirect after success.

If I run `this.props.history.push('/any')` inside component, it works! but I need to **run redirect inside thunk action** after successful `fetch()`

I was trying wrap all components with `withRouter` or `Route`, but didn't help.

Comment: Which version of `react-router-redux` do you use? You need to use `react-router-redux` v5 which will be compatible with `react-router` v4. Th package `react-router-redux` v5 currently is actively developed.

Comment: @oklas Now I tried run it on `react-router-redux` v5 but it behave the same like v4

Comment: Most probably this is not implemented yet. As workaround Delegate this to component where `router` `history` object is available. Your push event always appear at the end of thunk queue so you can set state with redirect info.

Comment: Can you provide the <Router /> code please?

Comment: **Edited** questing by providing more code and I also put one answer how I worked-around this issue, but still waiting if someone comes with the solution how to redirect directly from the thunk action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `history` object into your component and use push like this:

```jsx
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

@withRouter
@connect(({auth})=>({auth}))
class App extends Component {

  // on redux state change
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(!nextProps.auth)
      this.props.history.push('/login')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          // on button click
          onClick={this.props.history.push('/')}
        >
          Home page
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks there will be no better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I share your joy.

Answer (score 0):

I made workaround by delegating state of successfull fetch() to the component (thanks @oklas) where is `history.push()` or `<Redirect>` working:

```
{this.props.fetchSuccessfull && <Redirect to="/any" />}
```

But still waiting for better solution by calling push() directly from thunk action.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me then submit another not perfect solution by passing the history object in the dispatch to the action. I guess it's more a beginners-solution but is IMHO simple to understand (and therefore simple to maintain which is the most important thing in software-development)

Using <BrowserRouter> makes all React-compoments having the history in their props. Very convenient. But, as the problem description stated, you want it outside a React Component, like an action on Redux-Thunk.

Instead of going back to <Router> I chose to stick to BrowserRouter.

- The history object cannot be accessed outside React Components
- I did not like going back to <Router> and using something like react-router-redux

Only option left is to pass along the history object to the action.

**In a Auth-ForgotPassword component:**

```
const submitHandler = (data) => {
   dispatch(authActions.forgotpassword({data, history:props.history}));
}
```

**In the action function**

```
export const forgotpassword = ({forgotpasswordData, history}) => {
   return async dispatch => {
        const url = settings.api.hostname + 'auth/forgotpassword'; // Go to the API
        const responseData = await fetch(
            url,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(forgotpasswordData),
            }
        );
        history.push('/auth/forgotpassword/success');
    }
}
```

And now we all wait for the final elegant solution :-)